# Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.START

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

I tried to use AdMob with test ads in flutter. I always receive **code 3**
.........................................................................

android/build.gradle

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 33

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}


distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip


environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.2 <3.0.0'

google_mobile_ads: ^2.3.0
```

............................................................................
main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); 
  await MobileAds.instance.initialize().then(
    (InitializationStatus status) {
      MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(
        RequestConfiguration(
          tagForChildDirectedTreatment:
              TagForChildDirectedTreatment.unspecified,
          testDeviceIds: <String>[
            myDevice, 
          ],
        ),
      );
      debugPrint('Initialization done: ${status.adapterStatuses}');
    },
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

............................................................................
home_page.dart

```
BannerAd? _anchoredAdaptiveAd;
  bool _isLoaded = false;
  late Orientation _currentOrientation;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _currentOrientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    _loadAd();
    mess();
  }

  /// Load another ad, disposing of the current ad if there is one.
  Future<void> _loadAd() async {
    await _anchoredAdaptiveAd?.dispose();
    setState(() {
      _anchoredAdaptiveAd = null;
      _isLoaded = false;
    });

    final AnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize? size =
        await AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.truncate());

    if (size == null) {
      print('Unable to get height of anchored banner.');
      return;
    }

    _anchoredAdaptiveAd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: myBanner,
      size: size,
      request: const AdRequest(),
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
          print('$ad loaded: ${ad.responseInfo}');
          setState(() {
            // When the ad is loaded, get the ad size and use it to set
            // the height of the ad container.
            _anchoredAdaptiveAd = ad as BannerAd;
            _isLoaded = true;
          });
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
          print('Anchored adaptive banner failedToLoad: $error');
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
    );
    return _anchoredAdaptiveAd!.load();
  }

  /// Gets a widget containing the ad, if one is loaded.
  ///
  /// Returns an empty container if no ad is loaded, or the orientation
  /// has changed. Also loads a new ad if the orientation changes.
  Widget _getAdWidget() {
    return OrientationBuilder(
      builder: (context, orientation) {
        if (_currentOrientation == orientation &&
            _anchoredAdaptiveAd != null &&
            _isLoaded) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            width: _anchoredAdaptiveAd!.size.width.toDouble(),
            height: _anchoredAdaptiveAd!.size.height.toDouble(),
            child: AdWidget(ad: _anchoredAdaptiveAd!),
          );
        }
        // Reload the ad if the orientation changes.
        if (_currentOrientation != orientation) {
          _currentOrientation = orientation;
          _loadAd();
        }
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }


body: _getAdWidget();
```

***Log.................................................................................
.
.
.
.***

```
I/Ads     (29864): This request is sent from a test device.
Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.START
W/Ads     (29864): Not retrying to fetch app settings
I/Ads     (29864): Ad failed to load : 3
I/flutter (29864): BannerAd failedToLoad: LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: [], loadedAdapterResponseInfo: null), responseExtras: {mediation_group_name: BannerGroup, mediation_ab_test_name: BannerGroup_Feb 9, mediation_ab_test_variant: Variant A})
```

Comment: same here, seems it if fresh issue on Firebase side.

Comment: You don't need to add anything in build.gradle , just follow the solution bellow .

Comment: if you have any question or any error don't hesitate to ask again .

Answer (score 3):

Inside your android/app/src/main/androidManifest.xml add inside `<application> </application>`
This line

```
<meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
       android:value="ca-app-pub-[your id]" />
```

[your id] = your own adMob id .

And to support android 12 & 13 add the line bellow after `</application>`

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

Comment: Doesnt work. I am receiving this error after bumping the google libs.

Comment: If you receive Ad failed to load : 3 that means that you have done every thing succesfully , the error 3 means that google ads has no ads to show at that moment , you shoud just wait until they show ads for you . but probably if you tried another device (Real phone) it will show ads .

Comment: how long to wait?

Comment: Don't wait just upload your app on google play , and it will be working , the problem is just with your device .

Answer (score 2):

1-Uninstall your application from your test device
2- Connect your device to the android studio
3- Install again then the ads will start loading

:-It workes for me